# Interface for generic class

Tags: java, interface

I have a class structure like follows

```
 public class GenericProcess<T> implements Serializable {
     private final Map<String, Map<String, T>>  process = new HashMap<String, Map<String, T>>();

    void setProcess(String key, T value){
    }

    T getProcess(string key){
    }

 }
```

How i can implement a Readonly interface for this class in which I will have only getters and no setters.

Comment: Make your maps unmodifable using `Collections.unmodifiableMap()`?

Comment: I want an interface where only getters are avaiable..

Answer (score 3):

Make an interface such as:

```
public interface ReadOnlyProcess<T>
{
    T getProcess(String key);
    // etc
}
```

and make your `GenericProcess<T>` implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface `GenericInterface<T>`  and implement this interface in "GenericProcess" class and place only the getter methods inside the interface.